# One-Sample t Test Accept or Reject

Tags: r, p-value

I have the following list:

```
> str1<-'cor 0.9834559 0.9816176 0.9797794 0.9926471'
> df1 <- read.table(text=scan(text=str1, what='', quiet=TRUE), header=TRUE)
> t.test (df1, mu=0.9816176, alternative = "less", conf.level = 0.95)

    One Sample t-test

data:  df1
t = 0.96491, df = 3, p-value = 0.7971
alternative hypothesis: true mean is less than 0.9816176
95 percent confidence interval:
      -Inf 0.9911001
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 0.984375
```

I would like to get in accordance to the t-test one decision: `Accept` or `Reject` hypothesis H0. In this case since `p-value > 0.05` I'm supposed to accept H0.
How can I get automatically the relevant result?

Comment: You can extract the p-value and use a if statement. For extracting you can use `$p.value` eg  `t.test (df1, mu=0.9816176, alternative = "less", conf.level = 0.95)$p.value`

Comment: what do you mean by automatically get the relevant result?

Comment: I mean that I'll get the result from the t-test as ACCEPT or REJECT.

Comment: @Avi you can not accept null hypothesis (H0). The only result of test is that you can reject null hypothesis or that you do not have enough proof to reject it. You never accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution based on the comments. It involves writing a function that will extract the relevant `p.value` from the object created in the t-test:

```
auto <- function(x) {
  z <- t.test(x, mu=mean(x), alternative = "less", conf.level = 0.95)
  if (z$p.value > 0.05) {
    print("ACCEPT H0") 
    }  else {
    print("REJECT H0")
  }
}
#call the function
auto(df1$cor)
#[1] "ACCEPT H0"
```